# How do Divinity Runes calculate percentages?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I have 181 magic armor. I equip a Medium Masterwork Rune that says "Maximum magic armor +20%". How is it that I only get 5 more magic armor? Seems I used a lot of valuable resources to make things to upgrade to medium and then I realized it does't do much at all.

Comment: What is your magic armor at? Magic armor and regular armor are two completely different stats.

Comment: 181 magic armor. I didn’t say physical or magical but thought it was implied. I’ll update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Runes only increase the armour of the piece of equipment they're slotted in, not your total armour.

Comment: ^ this is what I was gonna say. So basically put it on something with high magic armor

Comment: It's funny because it only adds to magic armor on an amulet so it doesn't get amazing until an amulet has an amazingly high number (I'm lvl 12 right now)